# Youtube video comment status can't be changed from "heldForReview" to any other

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I tried to change youtube video comment status from "published" to "heldForReview" by using following API and I am successfully changed the status of the comment.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments/setModerationStatus?id={COMMENT_ID}&moderationStatus=heldForReview&key={API_KEY}

When I tried to change comment status from "heldForReview" to "published" (using the same above API with moderationStatus=published) I have received following error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.comment",
    "reason": "processingFailure",
    "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "id"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid."
 }
}
```

I also tried to change status of comment from "heldForReview" to "published" using google developers API explorer but received same error.

I would really appreciate any solution.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have an invalid ID for your input. To correctly get the comment ID you can click the date of the comment

[image]

which will change the url to this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[ID]&lc=[ID]
```

use the value of lc to have a correct ID then you'll have a successful request that can change the comment status. Also you'll have to use OAuth 2.0 for request authorization. Hope this helps.